# Trying to create a To-do list that gets stored into local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Hey I am a relatively new to coding and currently attending a boot camp and one of the assignments is to build a to-do list that is saved even when the user refreshes. I have the to-do list working but I can't seem to save it after a refresh and I am always getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse".
This is the chunk of code where I think the issue is. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
    const saved = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || [];

for (let i = 0; i < saved.length; i++) {
    let newTodo = document.createElement("li");
    newTodo.innerText = saved[i].objective;
    newTodo.isCompleted = saved[i].isCompleted ? true : false;
        if (newTodo.isCompleted) {
            newTodo.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  }
  list.appendChild(newTodo);
}

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let newTodo = document.createElement("li");
  let Value = document.getElementById("objective").value;
  newTodo.innerText = Value;
  newTodo.isCompleted = false;
  form.reset();
  list.appendChild(newTodo);
  saved.push({ objective: newTodo.innerText, isCompleted: false });
  localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(saved));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Test if the item is null:

```
const item = localStorage.getItem("todos");
const saved = item !== null ? JSON.parse(item) : [];
```